# How to play online radio streaming url in Android. How to play .pls radio streaming url in android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-mediaplayer, internet-radio

I created a XML file in my server. It contains `title` and `link` tags. I fetch the tags and display them as links in `ListView`. From there when the user clicks the link, then I'd like play the `.pls` file in the Radio Station app.

Here is my XML file:

```
<item>
    <title> Kushi FM </title>
    <link>http://108.163.197.114:8071/listen.pls</link>
</item>
```

I don't know how to play the link in next activity.

`MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // All static variables
    static final String URL1 = "http://servernmae.com/stations";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
    URL url;

    URLConnection urlConnection;
    //Context context;
    ListView listview;
    int images=R.drawable.radio;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       // isNetworkAvailable(this);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        if(isNetworkAvailable(this))
        {
            new GetData().execute();

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Connect to Internet and Check Again ! Thanks)",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



    }
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                    Log.w("INTERNET:",String.valueOf(i));
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        Log.w("INTERNET:", "connected!");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String xml = "error";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                url = new URL(URL1);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isw);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                br.close();

                xml = sb.toString();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return xml;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            ArrayList<String> title= new ArrayList<>();
            //title.add("");

            Document doc = null;
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {

                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

                InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is);


                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    Log.e("TAg1", getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                    //Log.e("TAg2", getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
                    map.put(KEY_TITLE, getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                    map.put(KEY_LINK, getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
                    menuItems.add(map);

                    title.add(getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                }


            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());

            }
            String[] dataArr = new String[title.size()];
            dataArr = title.toArray(dataArr );
            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), dataArr );
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //HashMap<String, String> selectedMap = menuItems.get(position);
                    HashMap<String,String> selectedMap= menuItems.get(position);
                    String urls = selectedMap.get(KEY_LINK);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Service_Player.class);
                    intent.putExtra("url",urls);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

            });




        }

        public final String getElementValue(Node elem) {
            Node child;
            if (elem != null) {
                if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
                    for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()) {
                        if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                            return child.getNodeValue();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

        public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }


    }
```

`Service_player.java`

```
public class Service_Player extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_service__player);
        startService(new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class));
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url))
            startMediaPlayer(url);


    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiverFromservice, new IntentFilter(MediaPlayerService.SERVICE_TO_ACTIVITY));
    }

    private String currentPlayerStatus = "N/A";
    private BroadcastReceiver receiverFromservice = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (MediaPlayerService.SERVICE_TO_ACTIVITY.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
                /*
                * To get current status of player
                * */
                currentPlayerStatus = intent.getStringExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_STATUS_KEY);
                Log.e("Player Mode", "" + currentPlayerStatus);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiverFromservice);
    }
    public void startMediaPlayer(String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE, MediaPlayerService.PLAY_MEDIA_PLAYER);
        intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_TRACK_URL, url);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

MediaPlayerService.java

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service {

    public static final String BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE = "com.mediaplayer.playerfunction";
    public static final String SERVICE_TO_ACTIVITY = "com.mediaplayer.currentPlayerStatus";
    public static final String PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE = "playerfunction";
    public static final String PLAYER_TRACK_URL = "trackURL";
    public static final int PLAY_MEDIA_PLAYER = 1;
    public static final int PAUSE_MEDIA_PLAYER = 2;
    public static final int RESUME_MEDIA_PLAYER = 3;
    public static final int STOP_MEDIA_PLAYER = 4;
    public static final int CHANGE_PLAYER_TRACK = 5;
    public static final String PLAYER_STATUS_KEY = "PlayerCurrentStatus";
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE);
        registerReceiver(playerReceiver, intentFilter);
        if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            sendPlayerStatus("playing");
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver playerReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
                String trackURL = intent.hasExtra(PLAYER_TRACK_URL) ? intent.getStringExtra(PLAYER_TRACK_URL) : "";
                int function = intent.getIntExtra(PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE, 0);
                switch (function) {
                    case CHANGE_PLAYER_TRACK:
                        changeTrack(trackURL);
                        break;
                    case STOP_MEDIA_PLAYER:
                        stopPlayer();
                        break;
                    case PLAY_MEDIA_PLAYER:
                        startMediaPlayer(trackURL);
                        break;
                    case PAUSE_MEDIA_PLAYER:
                        pausePlayer();
                        break;
                    case RESUME_MEDIA_PLAYER:
                        resumePlayer();
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    };
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    private void pausePlayer() {
        if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
            sendPlayerStatus("pause");
        }
    }

    private void resumePlayer() {
        if (mPlayer != null && !mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.start();
            sendPlayerStatus("playing");
        }
    }

    private void changeTrack(String url) {
        stopPlayer();
        startMediaPlayer(url);

    }

    private void stopPlayer() {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
            sendPlayerStatus("stopped");

        }
    }

    public void startMediaPlayer(String url) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(url))
            return;
        if (mPlayer == null)
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    if (extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED
                            || extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED) {
                        sendPlayerStatus("erroronplaying");
                    } else if (extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO) {
                        sendPlayerStatus("erroronplaying");
                        return false;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            mPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

                public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                    Log.e("onBufferingUpdate", "" + percent);

                }
            });
            mPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mPlayer.start();
                    sendPlayerStatus("playing");
                }
            });
            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Log.e("onCompletion", "Yes");
                    sendPlayerStatus("completed");
                }
            });
            mPlayer.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sendPlayerStatus(String status) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(SERVICE_TO_ACTIVITY);
        intent.putExtra(PLAYER_STATUS_KEY, status);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

`Manifest.xml`

```
<!-- Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Service_Player"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_service__player" >
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MediaPlayerService"></service>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll suggest you to use **[Service](http://goo.gl/UwmN7P)** if you are creating app with MediaPlayer streaming or normal MediaPlayer. It will be easy to handle player background & centrally.

To use media player in Service you can use it with **[BroadCastReceiver](http://goo.gl/TrCXdl)** or Bound Service as per your requirement.It would be good if MediaPlayer related service if you keep it **[running in foreground](http://goo.gl/Gdt3VS)** here in below code I have not handle for that please check the given link.

Here in sample code i have used BroadCast Receiver to send command from Activity to Service for MediaPlayer(like play ,pause, change track etc) and vice versa.

Now to get url which you are sending from Activity onItemClickListner ,you need to get from Intent.

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
```

**PlayerScreen**

```
    public class PlayerScreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);
        startService(new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class));
        findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTrack).setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        findViewById(R.id.btnStartMediaPlayer).setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        findViewById(R.id.btnStopMediaPlayer).setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglePauseResume);
        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener);
        /*
        * To get url which is passing from the previous activity listitem click.
        * If url which is pass from listitem click is not empty it will start player
        * */
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url))
            startMediaPlayer(url);

    }

    private ToggleButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkedChangeListener = new ToggleButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (!isChecked) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE, MediaPlayerService.PAUSE_MEDIA_PLAYER);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE, MediaPlayerService.RESUME_MEDIA_PLAYER);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    private View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent;
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnChangeTrack:
                    intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE, MediaPlayerService.CHANGE_PLAYER_TRACK);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_TRACK_URL, "http://69.64.41.64:9938");
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.btnStartMediaPlayer:
                    startMediaPlayer("http://108.163.197.114:8071/listen.pls");
                    break;
                case R.id.btnStopMediaPlayer:
                    intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE, MediaPlayerService.STOP_MEDIA_PLAYER);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                    break;

            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiverFromservice, new IntentFilter(MediaPlayerService.SERVICE_TO_ACTIVITY));
    }

    private String currentPlayerStatus = "N/A";
    private BroadcastReceiver receiverFromservice = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (MediaPlayerService.SERVICE_TO_ACTIVITY.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
                /*
                * To get current status of player
                * */
                currentPlayerStatus = intent.getStringExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_STATUS_KEY);
                Log.e("Player Mode", "" + currentPlayerStatus);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiverFromservice);
    }

    /**
     * TO start media player.It will send broadcast to Service & from service player will start
     *
     * @param url
     */
    public void startMediaPlayer(String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE, MediaPlayerService.PLAY_MEDIA_PLAYER);
        intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_TRACK_URL, url);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

**MediaPlayerService**

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service {
    public static final String BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE = "com.mediaplayer.playerfunction";
    public static final String SERVICE_TO_ACTIVITY = "com.mediaplayer.currentPlayerStatus";
    public static final String PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE = "playerfunction";
    public static final String PLAYER_TRACK_URL = "trackURL";
    public static final int PLAY_MEDIA_PLAYER = 1;
    public static final int PAUSE_MEDIA_PLAYER = 2;
    public static final int RESUME_MEDIA_PLAYER = 3;
    public static final int STOP_MEDIA_PLAYER = 4;
    public static final int CHANGE_PLAYER_TRACK = 5;
    public static final String PLAYER_STATUS_KEY = "PlayerCurrentStatus";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE);
        registerReceiver(playerReceiver, intentFilter);
        if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            sendPlayerStatus("playing");
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver playerReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
                String trackURL = intent.hasExtra(PLAYER_TRACK_URL) ? intent.getStringExtra(PLAYER_TRACK_URL) : "";
                int function = intent.getIntExtra(PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE, 0);
                switch (function) {
                    case CHANGE_PLAYER_TRACK:
                        changeTrack(trackURL);
                        break;
                    case STOP_MEDIA_PLAYER:
                        stopPlayer();
                        break;
                    case PLAY_MEDIA_PLAYER:
                        startMediaPlayer(trackURL);
                        break;
                    case PAUSE_MEDIA_PLAYER:
                        pausePlayer();
                        break;
                    case RESUME_MEDIA_PLAYER:
                        resumePlayer();
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    };
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    private void pausePlayer() {
        if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
            sendPlayerStatus("pause");
        }
    }

    private void resumePlayer() {
        if (mPlayer != null && !mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.start();
            sendPlayerStatus("playing");
        }
    }

    private void changeTrack(String url) {
        stopPlayer();
        startMediaPlayer(url);

    }

    private void stopPlayer() {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
            sendPlayerStatus("stopped");

        }
    }

    public void startMediaPlayer(String url) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(url))
            return;
        if (mPlayer == null)
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    if (extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED
                            || extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED) {
                        sendPlayerStatus("erroronplaying");
                    } else if (extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO) {
                        sendPlayerStatus("erroronplaying");
                        return false;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            mPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

                public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                    Log.e("onBufferingUpdate", "" + percent);

                }
            });
            mPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mPlayer.start();
                    sendPlayerStatus("playing");
                }
            });
            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Log.e("onCompletion", "Yes");
                    sendPlayerStatus("completed");
                }
            });
            mPlayer.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sendPlayerStatus(String status) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(SERVICE_TO_ACTIVITY);
        intent.putExtra(PLAYER_STATUS_KEY, status);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

**player.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ab_tool"
        android:text="Home" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStartMediaPlayer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
        android:text="Start Player" />


    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/togglePauseResume"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnStartMediaPlayer"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textOff="Resume"
        android:textOn="Pause" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChangeTrack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/togglePauseResume"
        android:text="Chanage Track" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStopMediaPlayer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnChangeTrack"
        android:text="STOP" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".PlayerScreen">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<service android:name=".MediaPlayerService"></service>
```

To get data from streaming url header data you can [check this answer](http://goo.gl/mmr9ji)

For testing purpose here i have used two urls

***UPDATE***
**PlayerActivity**

```
public class PlayerScreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);
        startService(new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class));
        /*
        * To get url which is passing from the previous activity listitem click.
        * If url which is pass from listitem click is not empty it will start player
        * */
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url))
            startMediaPlayer(url);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiverFromservice, new IntentFilter(MediaPlayerService.SERVICE_TO_ACTIVITY));
    }

    private String currentPlayerStatus = "N/A";
    private BroadcastReceiver receiverFromservice = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (MediaPlayerService.SERVICE_TO_ACTIVITY.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
                /*
                * To get current status of player
                * */
                currentPlayerStatus = intent.getStringExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_STATUS_KEY);
                Log.e("Player Mode", "" + currentPlayerStatus);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiverFromservice);
    }

    /**
     * TO start media player.It will send broadcast to Service & from service player will start
     *
     * @param url
     */
    public void startMediaPlayer(String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE, MediaPlayerService.PLAY_MEDIA_PLAYER);
        intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_TRACK_URL, url);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

let me know if anything.

Comment: Thanks But When User Click the Fm Name in Listview The Next Activity will play Automatically How can we do it ???

Comment: Here is the Code I Write in NextActivity is tht Right? Intent intent= getIntent();
        final String selectedData = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        fmname.setText(selectedData);
 mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(selectedData);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });

Comment: `Player` Activity from my answer will be your `Service_Player` in `Player` activity 's `onCreate` method it will fetch url data from intent and its calling `startMediaPlayer` method which will start player

Comment: Thanks I got it But What My Doubt is In The Next Activity i am Not place any Buttons (like Start or Stop )its an Empty Activity the radio want to play here..But in your Coading u use Switch statement by button id and play that File but i am not using any button How can we Do it ? @user1140237

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102076/discussion-between-vasanth-and-user1140237).

Comment: @vasanth whats the error or issue are you getting ? as it worked with the given url (which i have used) your url which is question is not responding(NOT found) error

Comment: It DoesNot play Radio(Sound)

Comment: I check Whether i am pass the url to Next activity its working but the radio(sound) was Not Working i think there some problem in Media PLayer  @user1140237

Comment: @vasanth as you said _i have 6 .pls files only 3 was failed others are working_ so can you please check that url in VLC ? because if some of the url is not working & others are working in same code so chance is like streaming media format is not supported in android. and if possible than give that URL or pls file if its live

Comment: sorry @vasanth cant help you more if the issue with code than i can help you out but this issue is with your streaming url format. because if issue is with code than other URL should not work not even the URL which i gave its also PLS url from shout cast.

Comment: Ya i Accepted The Issue in My Url But 2 of the Url Link was Only Broken other are Working Good i Check tht in my iphone app and also in Vlc..i cant undestand y the other Working link was not Playing??

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaPlayer mp;
mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse(url))
//Example url of  .pls file http://50.xx.xxx.xx:xx40/)

mp.start();
mp.pause();
mp.release() (or mp.reset() as applicable)
```